# View layout that are initially hidden, then onclick will make view visible, and vice versa(Android)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, visibility

I have a constraint layout visibility that are initially set to GONE `expandableLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);`. I want to make the view to be visible when 'setOnClickListener' are issued. Then, when the user click the layout again the view will set to Gone Again.

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView mThicc;
        ListView listView;
        ConstraintLayout expandableLayout;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mThicc = itemView.findViewById(R.id.thicc);
            listView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.stocklist);
            expandableLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.expandableLayout);

            expandableLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            
            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    expandableLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            });

        }
    }
```

The problem is, when I clicked back the layout it wont stay hidden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing conditioning and checking if view is visible or gone like this on button click

```
if(expandableLayout.getVisibility==View.GONE){
    expandableLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
 else {
    expandableLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE); 
}
```

Comment: this one helps a lot. Since I am pulling data from firebase I just need to call 'notifyItemChanged(getAdapterPosition())' and it works like charm

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {     
        TextView mThicc;
        ListView listView;
        ConstraintLayout expandableLayout;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mThicc = itemView.findViewById(R.id.thicc);
            listView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.stocklist);
            expandableLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.expandableLayout);

            expandableLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            
            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    int visibility =  expandableLayout.getVisibility() == View.GONE ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE;
                    expandableLayout.setVisibility(visibility);
                }
            });

        }
    }
```

But I do not recommend this method, because it will lose its `visibility` state if the ViewHolder is recycled. You need to keep the visibility on the list item.